# Validations for password and confirm password

Tags: angular, typescript

I want my password and confirm password should be compare the value input.
When i input the same value in both password and confirm password, then also it is showing the 'Password does not match' error

Component

```
validate(): boolean {
    this.appErrors = [];

    if (this.objAppUser.UserName == '') {
      this.appErrors.push({ Title: 'User name cannot be blank.' });
    }
    if (this.objAppUser.LoginName == '') {
      this.appErrors.push({ Title: 'Login name cannot be blank.' });
    }
    if (this.objAppUser.Password == '') {
      this.appErrors.push({ Title: 'Password cannot be blank.' });
    }    
    if (this.objAppUser.Password !== this.objAppUser.ConfirmPassword) {
      this.appErrors.push({ Title: 'Password does not match.' });
    }
    if (this.objAppUser.UserCategoryId == 0) {
      this.appErrors.push({ Title: 'UserCategory name cannot be blank.' });
    }

    if (this.appErrors.length > 0) {
      return false;
    }
    else {
      return true;
    }
  }
```

html

```
  <div>
                    <mat-form-field class="width-size">
                        <input type="password" matInput [(ngModel)]="objAppUser.password" placeholder="Password" name="passwordCtrl">
                    </mat-form-field>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <mat-form-field class="width-size">
                        <input type="password" matInput placeholder="Confirm Password" name="confirmpasswordCtrl">
                    </mat-form-field>
                </div>
```

Comment: *First:* please ensure that when you send you form you are not submitting it.. it will refresh your from state and maybe you relay on this state for your validation. *Second:* please add `console.log(this.objAppUser)` in `validate` method and send it here please

Comment: You forgot to add `[(ngModel)]="objAppUser.ConfirmPassword"` in confirm password field. As you are checking `if (this.objAppUser.Password !== this.objAppUser.ConfirmPassword)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use : **[ngx-custom-validators](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-custom-validators)** , that will make your work too easy ( for all kind of custom validations too )

With this, all we need to do is `[equalTo]="password"`

**HTML**

```
<form [formGroup]='changePasswordForm' novalidate>
    <div class="ele">
        <label>New Password</label>
        <input type="password" ngModel name="password" #password="ngModel" required>
        <p *ngIf="password.errors?.required">required error</p>
    </div>
    <div class="ele">
        <label>Confirm Password</label>
        <input type="password" ngModel name="certainPassword" #certainPassword="ngModel" [equalTo]="password">
        <p *ngIf="certainPassword.errors?.equalTo">equalTo error</p>
    </div>
</form>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-confirm-password)** ( Reactive + TemplateDriven )